# Conditionally attach event listener and handler to Vue component

Tags: vue.js, event-handling

I have a Vue component that is used several places in my app. In some of these cases, I need to handle a click event with a specific function, like:

```html
<div @click="checkNav" />
```

However, I would only like to attach this handler when needed, so it doesn't fire unnecessarily when it's not needed.

I've tried passing a prop to the component and attaching the handler conditionally, like so:

```html
<div @click="isCheckNeeded ? checkNav : null" />
```

and then in props, I've specified:

```js
isCheckNeeded {
  type: Boolean,
  required: false,
  default: false,
}
```

However, my `checkNav` function never fires, and I've double checked that `isCheckNeeded` is true in Vue devtools.

Is this kind of conditional check not possible, or not recommended? Is there a better way to conditionally attach event listeners/handlers?

Answer (score 5):

It might help to see how your template is being compiled to understand the cause of the problem...

When `v-on` receives a method name, `vue-template-compiler` compiles it into a method lookup, where the resolved method becomes the event handler [[1]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers). For instance, your template `<div @click="checkNav" />` is compiled into this render function:

```js
with (this) {
  return _c("div", { on: { click: checkNav } })
}
```

On the other hand with an [inline event handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers), `<div @click="isCheckNeeded ? checkNav : null" />` is compiled into this:

```js
with (this) {
  return _c("div", {
    on: {
      click: function ($event) {
        isCheckNeeded ? checkNav : null
      },
    },
  })
}
```

Notice a couple things here:

1. The expression is wrapped in an anonymous function, which becomes the event handler.
2. The result of the expression is either a *method name* (as opposed to a *method call*) or `null`. Evaluating a method name is effectively a no-op.

---

### Solution 1: Change method name into method call

This is probably the simplest solution, but it has the disadvantage of the handler always being invoked upon click (although a falsy `isCheckNeeded` would cause an early return).

```html
<!-- BEFORE: -->
<!--
<div @click="isCheckNeeded ? checkNav : null" />
-->

<!-- AFTER: -->
<div @click="isCheckNeeded ? checkNav() : null" />

<!-- OR: -->
<div @click="isCheckNeeded && checkNav()" />
```

### Solution 2: Use dynamic event

This is slightly more complex, but it has the advantage of registering the event handler only when necessary. The event handler is automatically unregistered when `isCheckNeeded` is falsy.

```html
<div @[clickEvent]="checkNav" />
...
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    clickEvent() {
      return this.isCheckNeeded ? 'click' : null
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `<div @[clickEvent]="checkNav"><slot/></div>`,
  props: {
    isCheckNeeded: Boolean
  },
  computed: {
    clickEvent() {
      return this.isCheckNeeded ? 'click' : null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkNav() {
      console.log('checkNav')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      isCheckNeeded: false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.click-area {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="isCheckNeeded = !isCheckNeeded">Toggle click handler</button>
  <pre>isCheckNeeded={{isCheckNeeded}}</pre>

  <my-component :is-check-needed="isCheckNeeded">
    <div class="click-area">
      <span v-if="isCheckNeeded">Click me!</span>
      <span v-else>Clicking ignored</span>
    </div>
  </my-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uses `@click="enabled && clickHandler($event)"`.

```js
new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data () {
    return {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickHandler: function () {
      console.info('clicked')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <a @click="enabled && clickHandler($event)">
        Test: {{enabled}}
        </a>
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="enabled">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Another option** is use `render function` like below:

```js
new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  render (h) {
    let props = {}
    if (this.enabled) {
      this.$set(props, 'on', {click: this.clickHandler})
    }
    let self = this
    return h('div', [
      h('input', {
        attrs: {type: 'checkbox'}, 
        domProps: {checked: this.enabled}, 
        on: {
          input: function (event) {
            self.enabled = event.target.checked
          }
        }
      }),
      h('a', props, `Test: ${this.enabled}`)
    ])
  },
  data () {
    return {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickHandler: function () {
      console.info('clicked')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `v-if` statement to render the `div` with or without the click handler.

```
<div v-if="isCheckedNeeded" @click="checkNav"></div>
<div v-else></div>
```